# Vuex restoring imported Objects after filtering

Tags: vue.js, vuex

im struggling again with Vuex and an imported .js file.
I have 2 Buttons. The first on will initiate my Store and import a joke.js File with Jokes and load them into the state: jokes:[].
The second Button will delete the first Joke. 
But if i klick the first Button again, the first Joke will NOT be loaded again! Why????
My Store:

```
import jokesImportfrom './jokes'

export default {
  state: {
    jokes: []
  },
  mutations: {
    initJokes (state, payload) {
      state.jokes = payload;
    },
    filterJokes (state, deleteJoke) {
      for (let deletions in deleteJoke) {
        state.jokes.filter(element => {
          if (element.id === deleteJoke[deletions]) {
            state.jokes.splice(
              state.jokes.indexOf(element),
              1
            );
          }
        });
      }
    }
  },
  actions: {
    initStore ({ commit }) {
      commit('initJokes', jokesImport);

    },

    storeAnswer: ({ commit }, answer) => {
      commit("filterJokes", answer);
    },
  }
```

Is there something wrong with my Filter?
The Buttons have these both Methods on it:

```
getJokes() {
  this.$store.dispatch('initStore')
},
checkAnswer(answer){
  this.$store.dispatch("storeAnswer", {
    removeJoke: 1                        //This will remove the Joke with id: 1
  });
}
```

And the jikes.js look like this:

```
export default [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "question": "Did you hear about the restaurant on the moon?",
        "answer": "Great food, no atmosphere.",
        "votes": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "question": "What do you call a fake noodle",
        "answer": "An Impasta.",
        "votes": 0
    },
```

Comment: `splice` mutates the array when it is used.
Since the state is an array (reference type), when you use `splice` on `state.jokes` it will also mutate the object present in `jokes.js`.

Comment: what other method could I use instead of splice to remove object from my state.jokes, without mutating jokes.js?

Comment: Basically create a local variable, then use filter on `state.jokes`. 
Filter does not mutate the input array, it returns a new array.
You would have the `filtered` jokes now. 
Now update the state.jokes to filtered jokes by using `Vue.set` method.
It takes care of the reactivity.
Here is more on Vue.set : https://www.telerik.com/blogs/so-what-actually-is-vue-set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to make a deep copy of `jokesImport` when you are calling `initStore`.

If you do not do so, then when you change  `jokes`, it will also affect `jokesImport`.

Change your `initStore` action like this:

```
initStore({ commit }) {
    let init = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jokesImport)); //making deep copy.
    commit("initJokes", init);
  },
```

[image: Edit Vuex Store]